# Combing multiple excel files into different excel sheets in one workbook in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, merge, xlsx

I have multiple excel files, for example, e1.xlsx, e2.xlsx, and e3.xlsx I want to combine these files into one excel file e.xlsx and this file should consist of multiple sheets and each sheet should represent e1, e2, and e3 files.

Can this be done using R?

Comment: I'm sure this cane be done with library(openxlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can.  You may need the `writexl` package.

```
library(writexl)
library(readxl)

# your files
e1 <- read_xlsx("file1.xlsx")
e2 <- read_xlsx("file2.xlsx")
e3 <- read_xlsx("file3.xlsx")

my_sheets <- list(e1, e2, e3)

write_xlsx(my_sheets,"output.xls")
```